# Awk: How to take two columns from separate CSVs and add to new file

Tags: csv, awk

I have two files, each with the same number of columns and rows, named `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`. I am trying to create an awk script to take the second column from each file, and put them into a new file, `new.csv`, as separate columns (not combined into one); everything I've tried so far creates the new file with one column underneath the other one.

`file1.csv` looks like this:

```
num,avg,best
0,0.5,0.7
1,0.2,0.6
2,0.35,0.8
3,0.43,0.76
4,0.3,0.5
```

`file2.csv` looks like this:

```
num,avg,best
0,0.2,0.4
1,0.74,0.9
2,0.48,0.82
3,0.6,0.8
4,0.4,0.65
```

I've tried the following code to create the new file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","} {print $2}' file1.csv file2.csv > new.csv
```

However it outputs the following into `new.csv`:

```
avg
0.5
0.2
0.35
0.43
0.3
0.2
0.74
0.48
0.6
0.4
```

Whereas I would `new.csv` to look like the following:

```
0.5,0.2
0.2,0.74
0.35,0.48
0.43,0.6
0.3,0.4
```

I've done quite a lot of searching but I haven't found anything particularly useful (even though I'm fairly certain this is a pretty common thing to want to do?). I'm trying to figure this out on a small example because I have over 100 files that I need to take one column from and put into one file!

Any help is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$2
  next
}
{
  print a[FNR],$2
}' file1.csv  file2.csv
```

Output will be as follows.

```
0.5,0.2
0.2,0.74
0.35,0.48
0.43,0.6
0.3,0.4
```

Comment: @Chloe, yes correct.`FNR` is Line number which gets reset to `1`whenever a new Input_file starts getting read by awk. As e know `awk` could read multiple files at a time, so I used FNR to save line number for1st Input_file and used it to print its values while 2nd Input_file is beig read.